# MinGW (v2013072200) PATH variable loses drive letter for mingw/bin

Tags: windows, shell, gnu, mingw32

I run XP SP3 and installed MinGW (latest release, dated 20030722) to c:\MinGW.  I have data files (gcc source) on my G:\ drive.

I have added "c:\mingw\bin" to the path environmental variable.  When I start the mingw shell, the PATH variable shown by the shell ENV command ends with **":mingw/bin"** (not **":/c/**mingw\bin").  Other items in the windows path, eg c:\tools\, show as :/c/tools/: in the shell.

I conclude that what ever starts the shell looks for mingw\bin and *removes any drive specification.*

The problem is that in the shell, I CD over to my g: drive and run scripts which expect to implicitly find programs in mingw/bin.  They are not found, and I suspect this is because the search is made for g:\mingw\bin (not c:\mingw\bin).

This is another case of installers expecting every one to use a single large drive. Ugh!

**So how does one get the search aimed at c:\mingw\bin**, or run scripts to compile source that isn't on the c: drive?